# Jenks goodness of variance fit - Interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, optimization, k-means

I am working on clustering/grouping 1D data. I am trying to find bins of multiple variables seperately.

So, I tried the `jenks natural breaks algorithm`.

Based on the code from [here](https://github.com/gianfelton/RFM-Segmentation-with-Quartiles-Jenks-Natural-Breaks-and-HDBSCAN/blob/master/RFM%20Segmentation.ipynb), I managed to find the `goodness of variance fit` (GVF) for each of my variables.

I understand GVF closer to 1 is a good fit and closer to 0 is bad fit.

But now, looking at the below graphs, how do I select the number of classes?

All of them seem to have good score at n_classes = 9 but I see that after n_classes=5 there is no much improvement.

So, should I stick to n_classes = 5?

Is it purely a business decision and tradeoff between n_classes and GVF score?

**Or how can I know that n_classes = 5 is better than n_classes = 4 or n_classes = 9? How do we assess/judge whether my decision to choose n_classes = 5 is better than n_classes=4?**

**What does a value of 90% for GVF mean? Does it mean, 90% of the data for that group is well-separated from other groups?**

**What do you think would be the appropriate `n_classes` value for each of my variable?**

Can I seek your inputs on this?

[image]